# The video player library expo-av does not work in my react native local app

Tags: expo-av

When I run the following expo example through the expo Snack, it runs perfectly. Why does not work in my local expo app?, throwing the following error: " ERROR  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Copy the following expo example code and I tried to run in my local app...

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Video, ResizeMode } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {
  const video = React.useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Video
        ref={video}
        style={styles.video}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        }}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
        isLooping
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
      />
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <Button
          title={status.isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
          onPress={() =>
            status.isPlaying ? video.current.pauseAsync() : video.current.playAsync()
          }
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  video: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 320,
    height: 200,
  },
  buttons: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```